# Wordpress post feature image not uploading

Tags: admin, wp-admin, uploads

Wordpress admin side post page feature image not uploading.

Getting error like below
**An error occurred in the upload. Please try again later.**

Please give me answer.

Comment: Have you checked that file permissions for the upload folder are correct? http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions

Comment: Yes there is all permission on that folder.